# Action-listener implemented in Abstract Class does not get inherited by the classes who extend it

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Happy holidays to everyone,

Here is a use case of the situation i am trying to understand.

```
public abstract class Animal extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    private boolean actionFlag = false;

    //some constructor
    //some functions

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.actionFlag = true;
        System.out.println(this.actionFlag);
    }

}

public class Tiger extends Animal {}

public class Bear extends Animal {}
```

When for example `Tiger` and `Bear` objects getting created and they are BTN's cause the abstract method extends the `JButton` class, These buttons when getting pressed their respective `ActionPerformed()` function will get called, since I haven't overidden the `actionPerformed` func to each of these classes separately they will inherit the `actionPerformed()` from their parent class which is `Animal`, I believe I'm correct so far, if not feel free to correct me.

Now since all these observations are correct, when I click the bear button for example I should see that the message in my output equals to "true".

That's the problem, nothing appears on my console and it looks like the `actionListener` of the base class is not triggered at all .
(The buttons on the GUI are `setEnabled(true)` so the interaction is not a problem)

What are the possible causes of this? what am I missing here?

**Same thing happens with the `paintComponent()` function, but I believe that if I understand the error on the `actionListener` then it's kind of straightforward)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just giving a JButton-extending class an ActionListener ***doesn't add that listener to the created button***. To do that, you have to actually add the listener using `addActionListener(this);` in the class's constructor.

```
public abstract class Animal extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    private boolean actionFlag = false;

    public Animal() {
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    //some constructor
    //some functions

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.actionFlag = true;
        System.out.println(this.actionFlag);
    }
}
```

Having said that, I would never have Swing code like this, ever. Instead I would

- Extend by composition if possible, unless I absolutely needed to override an existing JButton method (and this needs to be justified)
- Separate my view class from my listener, even if this means using anonymous inner classes. It's rarely advisable to have a view class implement a listener interface as this breaks the "single responsibility principle" and increases the complexity and purpose of the class with no advantage

---

Regarding:

> Same thing happens with the `paintComponent()`

something different is likely happening here since you don't need to "add" paintComponent to the component, but rather *if it is a proper method override*, it is called automatically by the Swing graphics system.

Comment: Thanks lot for the response , you are right for the addActionListener , it seems i was too tired to think of it. As for the other suggestions , the code i provided is a simple example from a bigger project which needs the Jbutton extended cause im creating custom function on them. As for the paintComponent im aware of how it functions , it seems the problem is elsewhere in the project.

Comment: since ur answer solves my main problem i accept it and thanks lot